# Should I install iOS 8 on my iPhone 4s?

Tags: iphone, ios

What are the drawbacks of updating my iPhone 4s to the latest iOS? What are the advantages? With my phone plan, I cannot get the newest iPhone yet.

Comment: FWIW, I run iOS 8 on my 4S, and don't really see any drawbacks at all. Okay, it is perhaps not quite as responsive sometimes, taking some noticable fraction of a second to react to taps and swipes. It doesn't bother me, but others may feel differently.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages:

- more security
- more features: quick reply, continuity (if you have Mac &
  Yosemite )

  Disadvantages:
- it will run slowly
- you won't get a lot of the features that 5S and above have
- could decrease battery life

If you have experience with ssh and jailbreaking, I would say go ahead but make sure you can downgrade using ssh just in case you don't like it. 
However, if you don't even know what that is, I wouldn't recommend upgrading because there is no way to downgrade if you don't think you'll like it because apple already stopped signing ios7 and below.

Comment: Does Continuity work on a 4S?

Comment: @bassplayer7 here are the requirements for continuity.. Some features work while some don't.. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6555